# Array in tic-tac-toe ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

```
class Board extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
    };
  }

 
 handleClick(i) {

    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      squares: squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
  }

  renderSquare(i) {

    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

in this components state, the "squares" is an Array of nine null elements. I don't understand what it refers to as we have separately defined all the buttons in the renderSquare(). what does it define and is there any other way around it?

Comment: if add code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for debugging is great.

Comment: The array has nine positions. The `renderSquare` function receives one of the positions as an argument `(i)` and then returns a DOM element for that square - using the array to see what the state of that square is.

Answer (score 0):

The `state.squares` array in this example represents the current value on the Board.
The buttons you refer to are rendered as a `<Square>` element which *show* the value in the state for that particular index.

The `state.squares` array is initialized as an array of `null` elements, since the value is only set to `X` or `O` when the `<Square>` button is clicked.